# How to assign run configurations to icons at the top of Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I used to use this plugin which let me add icons to the top of Eclipse. Each icon would correspond to a run configuration.  http://sourceforge.net/projects/quicklaunch/

This project is old and doesn't work with the latest version of eclipse.

Is there an alternative way to do this or an alternative plugin that anyone knows about?  I want to be able to start my server and then start my client with two clicks total.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Eclipse Runner Plugin](https://code.google.com/p/eclipserunnerplugin/) plugin. Check this eclipse market place [link](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-runner).

This will not run/debug configuration to toolbar but it has separate view.